How to apply 2 animations (a circle with a rotating sector and a trajectory) on one PyQt5 window?
How to apply 2 animations (a circle with a rotating sector and a trajectory) on one PyQt5 window?Here is a piece of code where these functions work separately, the trajectory is taken from a JSON file.I tried to combine 2 animations into the update function, but nothing worked, because I don't understand how to use 'FuncAnimation' and what arguments to pass to it. I will be glad if you help me.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    
class MyFigurePolar(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self,width=5, height=4, dpi=100, fig = None, ax = None):
        if fig == None:
            self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
        else:
            self.fig = fig
            self.axes = ax
        super(MyFigurePolar, self).__init__(self.fig)


def anim_2d(self):
        data = self.file
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
        ax.set_xlabel("X")
        ax.set_ylabel("Y")
        ax.grid(True)

        points = make_points_between(data['trajectory']).T

        def update(num, points, ln):

            ln.set_data(np.arctan2(points[0, :num], points[1, :num]),
                        np.sqrt(points[0, :num] ** 2 + points[1, :num] ** 2))

            return ln,

        def update1(frame):
            ax.clear()
            r = 7
            period = np.pi / 64
            sector = ax.fill_between([], [], [], alpha=0.5, facecolor='red')  # Начинать с красного цвета
            theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
            ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
            ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
            ax.plot(theta, np.ones(100) * r, linestyle='-', color='black')
            start = frame * np.pi / 180
            end = start - period
            sector = ax.fill_between([start, end], 0, r, alpha=0.5, facecolor='red')
            ax.set_yticklabels([5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000])

            return sector,


        ln, = ax.plot(np.arctan2(points[0, 0:1], points[1, 0:1]), np.sqrt(points[0, 0:1] ** 2 + points[1, 0:1] ** 2))
        ax.set_xlim([np.min(points[0, :]), np.max(points[0, :])])
        ax.set_xlabel('X')

        ax.set_ylim([np.min(points[1, :]), np.max(points[1, :])])
        ax.set_ylabel('Y')

        self.anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(points[0]), fargs=(points, ln, None), interval=10000 / len(points[0]),
                              blit=False)
        self.anim0 = FuncAnimation(fig, update1, frames=360, fargs=(points, ln, None), interval=15, blit=True)

        return MyFigurePolar(fig=fig, ax=ax)

    def myfunc(self):
        F = self.anim_2d()


        self.gridlayout = QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridlayout.addWidget(F, 0, 1)

I tried to find information on the Internet, but I never found it.

To combine two animations into one PyQt5 window using FuncAnimation, you need to create a single update function that updates both animations simultaneously. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import json

class MyFigurePolar(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100, fig=None, ax=None):
        if fig is None:
            self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
        else:
            self.fig = fig
            self.axes = ax
        super(MyFigurePolar, self).__init__(self.fig)

def make_points_between(trajectory):
    # Dummy function for demonstration
    # You should implement this according to your JSON data structure
    return np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]])

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Animation Demo')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.figure_canvas = MyFigurePolar()
        layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas)

        self.anim_2d()
        self.anim_sector()

        self.show()

    def anim_2d(self):
        with open('trajectory.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        points = make_points_between(data['trajectory']).T
        self.ln, = self.figure_canvas.axes.plot(np.arctan2(points[0, 0:1], points[1, 0:1]),
                                                np.sqrt(points[0, 0:1] ** 2 + points[1, 0:1] ** 2))

        def update(num):
            self.ln.set_data(np.arctan2(points[0, :num], points[1, :num]),
                             np.sqrt(points[0, :num] ** 2 + points[1, :num] ** 2))
            self.update_sector(num)
            return self.ln,

        self.anim = FuncAnimation(self.figure_canvas.fig, update, frames=len(points[0]), interval=10000 / len(points[0]))

    def update_sector(self, frame):
        r = 7
        period = np.pi / 64
        self.sector.remove() if hasattr(self, 'sector') else None
        start = frame * np.pi / 180
        end = start - period
        self.sector = self.figure_canvas.axes.fill_between([start, end], 0, r, alpha=0.5, facecolor='red')
        self.figure_canvas.draw()

    def anim_sector(self):
        self.anim0 = FuncAnimation(self.figure_canvas.fig, self.update_sector, frames=360, interval=15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


In this code:

I created a MyWidget class that inherits from QWidget to hold the PyQt5 window.
In the initUI method of MyWidget, I created the layout and added the MyFigurePolar instance to it.
I added two methods anim_2d and anim_sector to handle the animations for the trajectory and the rotating sector, respectively.
In the anim_2d method, I load the trajectory data from a JSON file (you need to replace 'trajectory.json' with the path to your JSON file) and create the trajectory animation.
I defined an update function that updates both the trajectory and the sector animation simultaneously.
The update_sector method updates the sector animation.
Finally, I created a FuncAnimation instance for the sector animation in the anim_sector method.

This code should create a PyQt5 window with both animations running simultaneously. Adjust the file paths and animation parameters as needed for your application.
